# QXmlstreamreader trouble

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I am trying to read text inside a XML tag. I am using the readelementtext() function but it returns an empty Qstring. The code I am using is as follows;

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QFile>
#include <QStringList>
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QXmlStreamReader>
#include <QXmlStreamWriter>
#include <QByteArray>
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
#include <QString>

class XmlStreamLint
{
public:
    Q_DECLARE_TR_FUNCTIONS(XmlStreamLint)
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    enum ExitCode
    {
        Success,
        ParseFailure,
        ArgumentError,
        WriteError,
        FileFailure
    };

    QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);

    QTextStream errorStream(stderr);

    if (argc != 2)
    {
        errorStream << XmlStreamLint::tr(
                       "Usage: xmlstreamlint <path to XML file>\n");
        return ArgumentError;
    }

    QString inputFilePath(QCoreApplication::arguments().at(1));
    QFile inputFile(inputFilePath);

    if (!QFile::exists(inputFilePath))
    {
        errorStream << XmlStreamLint::tr(
                       "File %1 does not exist.\n").arg(inputFilePath);
        return FileFailure;

    } else if (!inputFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly|QIODevice::Text)) {
        errorStream << XmlStreamLint::tr(
                       "Failed to open file %1.\n").arg(inputFilePath);
        return FileFailure;
    }
    QString outputfilepath="/home/shakeel/xmlstreamlint/testing.xml";
    QFile outputFile(outputfilepath);
    //QFile outputFile;
    if (!outputFile.open(stdout, QIODevice::WriteOnly))
    {
        errorStream << XmlStreamLint::tr("Failed to open stdout.");
        return WriteError;
    }
    QByteArray array[20000];
    QByteArray *ptr;
    ptr=&array[0];
    QXmlStreamReader reader(&inputFile);
    //QXmlStreamWriter writer(&outputFile);
    QXmlStreamWriter writer(ptr);
    QString text,signal;
    int count=0;
    while (!reader.atEnd())
    {
        reader.readNext();

        if (reader.error())
        {
            errorStream << XmlStreamLint::tr(
                           "Error: %1 in file %2 at line %3, column %4.\n").arg(
                               reader.errorString(), inputFilePath,
                               QString::number(reader.lineNumber()),
                               QString::number(reader.columnNumber()));
            return ParseFailure;

        } else
            if (reader.isStartElement())
            {
                text = reader.name().toString();
                if(text.operator ==("TYPICAL_CYCLE_CHANNEL"))
                {
                           count=count+1;
                           signal=reader.readElementText();
                           writer.writeCurrentToken(reader);
```

The XML I am trying to read is as follows;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE ECG SYSTEM "mortara.dtd">
<!-- Generated by Mortara ELI Link 2.20 -->
<!-- Mortara Instrument, Inc. -->
<!-- Server Name - Unknown -->
  <ECG
    ACQUISITION_TIME="20070227033111"
    ROOM=""
    LOCATION=""
    COMMENT=""
    AGE="59"
    AGE_UNITS="Y"
    HEIGHT=""
    HEIGHT_UNITS="I"
    WEIGHT=""
    WEIGHT_UNITS="L"
    NUM_QRS="10"
    AVERAGE_RR="935"
    VENT_RATE="64"
    SEQUENCE_NUMBER="6"
  >
  <DEMOGRAPHIC_FIELD ID="1"  LABEL="Name:" VALUE="Asd" UNITS="" />
  <DEMOGRAPHIC_FIELD ID="7"  LABEL="FName:&amp;," VALUE="We" UNITS="" />
  <DEMOGRAPHIC_FIELD ID="2"  LABEL="ID&amp;ID:" VALUE="12" UNITS="" />
  <DEMOGRAPHIC_FIELD ID="16" LABEL="DOB:" VALUE="12/13/47" UNITS="" />
  <DEMOGRAPHIC_FIELD ID="3"  LABEL="Age&amp;yr" VALUE="59" UNITS="Y" />
  <DEMOGRAPHIC_FIELD ID="4"  LABEL="Sex" VALUE="Male" UNITS="" />
  <SITE
    ID="0"
  />
  <SUBJECT
    LAST_NAME="Asd"
    FIRST_NAME="We"
    GENDER="Male"
    ID="12"
  />
  <SOURCE
    TYPE="RESTING"
    MANUFACTURER="Mortara Instrument, Inc."
    MANUFACTURER_ID="10"
    MODEL="el250"
    ID="4"
    TRANSMISSION_TIME="20070414092347"
  />
    <AUTOMATIC_INTERPRETATION>
      <STATEMENT
        STATEMENT_NUMBER="1"
        TEXT="SINUS RHYTHM WITH SHORT PR INTERVAL"
        REASON=""
      />
      <STATEMENT
        STATEMENT_NUMBER="2"
        TEXT="TYPE A WOLFF-PARKINSON-WHITE PATTERN"
        REASON=""
      />
      <STATEMENT
        STATEMENT_NUMBER="3"
        TEXT="NO FURTHER INTERPRETATION POSSIBLE"
        REASON=""
      />
      <STATEMENT
        STATEMENT_NUMBER="4"
        TEXT="ATYPICAL ECG"
        REASON=""
      />
      <STATEMENT
        STATEMENT_NUMBER="5"
        TEXT=""
        REASON=""
      />
      <STATEMENT
        STATEMENT_NUMBER="6"
        TEXT="UNCONFIRMED REPORT"
        REASON=""
      />
    </AUTOMATIC_INTERPRETATION>
  <TYPICAL_CYCLE
    R_PEAK="500"
    P_ONSET="-185"
    P_OFFSET="-116"
    Q_ONSET="-87"
    Q_OFFSET="75"
    T_OFFSET="369"
    P_DURATION="69"
    PR_DURATION="98"
    QRS_DURATION="162"
    QT="456"
    QTC="465"
    QTCB="471"
    QTCF="466"
    P_AXIS="17"
    QRS_AXIS="-54"
    T_AXIS="108"
    BITS="16"
    FORMAT="SIGNED"
    UNITS_PER_MV="400"
    DURATION="1200"
    SAMPLE_FREQ="1000"
    ENCODING="BASE64"
  >
  <TYPICAL_CYCLE_CHANNEL
    NAME="I"
    DATA="BQAAAP7/AAAAAP7/AAACAAIAAgAAAP7//v/+/wAA/v8AAAIAAAAAAAIA/v/+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```

Comment: I tried to format your code (it will be visible if it is approved by moderators), but even then both your Qt code and the Xml doc are incomplete. If you are able to provide more complete code and Xml, you might get some answers.

Answer (score 0):

Dave
Let me re-post the code and the sample xml. Ihave removed the error catching conditionals.

```
QString inputFilePath(QCoreApplication::arguments().at(1));
QFile inputFile(inputFilePath);
QString outputfilepath="/home/shakeel/xmlstreamlint/testing.xml";
QFile outputFile(outputfilepath);
QByteArray array[2000];
QByteArray *ptr;
ptr=&array[0];
QXmlStreamReader reader(&inputFile);
QXmlStreamWriter writer(ptr);
QString text,signal;
while (!reader.atEnd())
{
    reader.readNext();
    } else
        if (reader.isStartElement())
        {
            text = reader.name().toString();
            if(text.operator ==("TYPICAL_CYCLE_CHANNEL"))
            {
           signal=reader.readElementtext();
            }
        }
        writer.writeCurrentToken(reader);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Just add closing braces the xml is complete
See if this helps
Regards